# exceeded your allotted storage space : Godaddy

Tags: backup, storage

I am hosting on Godaddy Windows hosting and all my websites are damn slow.

Is it because I am exceeding my storage space?

Storage space is used by backup manager. Will deleting backup resolve my website performance issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No... Of course not. If your sites working slowly, maybe they overload the server or there is troublemaker on the server that consume high resources on the server. This is something you need to check with your hosting provider. Or just to find reliable hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mark